# Developing HTML 5 apps for windows phone 8

Tags: windows, html, windows-phone-8

I did a little research and came to know that you can't develop c# apps for windows phone 8 without having a pc with windows 8 on it. That's sad, because I have windows 7. But windows 8 supports html 5 apps right? And I think I read somewhere that you can make metro apps for windows phone using html5 and css and javascript alone. The question is, shouldn't it be possible to develop these apps without the aid of windows 8 on your pc and visual studio? I simply hate the idea of having to use windows 8 just so that I can make programs for the phone. Windows 8 is nice to use on the phone, but I hate working with it on the pc.Simply put, I'd like to write html5 code in my beloved ubuntu (or windows 7) and deploy the app in my nokia lumia (and eventually the windows app store). I understand that I won't be able to emulate the phone from windows 7 or ubuntu. Workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write metro apps where the application logic is written in Javascript and the GUI is defined as a HTML5 document. But to glue it all together with the resources and compile it into a runable package you can deploy, you will need Visual Studio running on Windows 8.

When you prefer to work in Linux, you can run Windows 8 in a virtual machine and share the project directory between the Linux host and the Windows 8 guest. That way you can do most of the work in Linux and only need to switch to the Windows 8 VM to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i dont know if we can make a metro app with html5 but you can make a html5 native apps in Ubuntu or Mac or Windows 7/8.

PhoneGap is a framework that u can build a native mobile apps using Html5,css and javascript.

After you build your app you can make a .xap for WindowsPhone in Visual Studio.(just u need a visual studio 2010 or higher) You can take a look at the framework [here](http://phonegap.com/).